# Does Corretto complement BouncyCastle or does it replace it?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, corretto

Does Corretto JCE Provider complement BouncyCastle or does it replace it?  I know Bouncy supports more arcane formats than Sun JCA but generally I don't think I use them.  I am only after the secure algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of both.

BC is multiple things. It is an implementation of the JCE API. It is also its own API, because the JCE API is... not the bestest design.

Technically, you can have multiple JCE providers loaded in one VM. If you ask for some exotic format, the system will look for a provider that has it. In that sense, if BC supports something corretto's doesn't *and* vice versa it can make sense to load both and in that sense the complement, but... that sounds like quite a rare scenario.

I'm having a hard time imagining a sensible reason to load both corretto's and BCs, and if you're not using BC's own API, I doubt you need BC if already there, either.